# Compiler Sass it says Inconsistent indentation

Tags: css, sass

I have this in my main.sass:

```
24:     height: 444px
25:     background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0, .7), rgba(0,0,0, .7))
26:     position: relative
27: 
28:     .hero_background
29:      bottom: 0
30:      left: 0
31:      overflow: hidden
32:      position: absolute
33:      right: 0
34:      top: 0
```

When compiling, sass says:

```
/*
Error: Inconsistent indentation: "\t " was used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 1 tab. on line 29 of
```

**Is there a way to that I can fix this problem?**

Comment: what are the line 24,25 and 26 for to which element or class your applying and dont you wrap your code with {}

Comment: @Geeky when you are using SCSS you used Brackets but if you are using SASS you don't have to use brackets or ;.

Comment: what are the lines 24,25 and 26 for to which element/class it is

Comment: @Geeky do want top do a google hangout so I screen share my computer just show really quick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double tab your nested styles. It is telling you the issue right in the error.

Should look like this:

```
.hero_background{
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

line 29 and onwards has an extra space on each line